# How to pass authenticated session from a chatbot (nodejs app) to a web page?

Tags: security, authentication, chatbot

I have built a chatbot on Nodejs. It interacts with users on Slack, FB Messenger, or anything else theoretically. Users can authenticate with this bot. Sometimes text isn't the best medium and I need to show the user some information in a web browser. I provide a link to the dynamically generated page, but the page includes sensitive information.

How can I ensure that the user that follows the link from my chatbot is the same user that I gave the link to? Is there any method that does not involve asking the user to log in again?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can never ensure *any* link is being clicked on by the user you sent it to, unless you can ensure that it's only being sent to *them* and they have no way of sharing it. Since they *can* share it, you should just assume they won't, then just ensure the communication method is secure and the link is HTTPS.

To ensure the communication method is secure, you can make the chatbot privately send the message, for one. There are other methods, but it depends on what you'd find usable.

For the link itself, you can nullify it after an initial view. I.e., destroy the ability to generate the page again after it's been generated once.